# Getting incorrect output in java thread application?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

**Code :**

```
public class ThreadNaming extends Thread{
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("running");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ThreadNaming t1 = new ThreadNaming();

    t1.start();

    System.out.println(t1.getName());   
}   
}
```

**Doubt :** According to my understanding a thread starts executing the main function , once `t1.start()` is encountered a new call stack and a new thread is created . This newly created thread executes the run method , then control returns to original thread executing the `main()` function and next `System.out.println(t1.getName())` is executed so according to this flow output should be :

`running
Thread-0`

but eclipse is showing the following output

`Thread-0
running`

I have googled flow control of thread but didnt get anything and i am unable to understand why this is happening ? can anyone explain the reason for it with proper flow of control ?

**Note** : Thread-0 is name of thread

Unique Part : i don't want to implement the behaviour described in the other question , i want to know the reason how main thread and new thread are executing simultaneously because i read in a tutorial that a scheduler can only execute a single thread at a time .

Comment: Have you tried running it multiple times?

Comment: Yes i have tried , but everytime i am getting the wrong output

Comment: Saying "wrong" is a bit harsh :)

Comment: i know but i am a beginner i want to get my threading concepts right

Comment: When you run two threads Java is free to run them in whatever order it likes. You cannot rely on the order unless you add synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather it is entirely plausible that this happens.
At the beginning of `main`, the main thread is running. Then you create an instance of your `ThreadNaming` class. On the next line you call `t1.start();` which starts a *new thread*.

While this is called though, your main `Thread` can/will still run, calling `System.out.println(t1.getName());` *before* it gets to `System.out.println("running");` inside the `ThreadNaming` class. There is absolutely **no guarantee** that `run()` will be performed **before** the `getName()` call.

In order to force synchronization between your threads you will have to use some other methods such as [`wait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) (with [`notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())) and [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

Note: you are usually [better off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread) `implement`ing `Runnable` than `extend`ing `Thread`.

Comment: but in a tutorial i studied that a scheduler can execute only a single thread at a time . now if this is correct then how main thread is executing while new thread is being created ?

Comment: They can run simultaneously if you have a multiprocessor computer (but even if you don't, Java can still choose whichever Thread to run at a given time, meaning your output is still ok)